# How to chain mapper/reducer in Hadoop 1.0.4?

Tags: java, api, hadoop, mapreduce, version

I was using "new" API of Hadoop 1.0.4 (classes in package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce). When I wanted to chain mapper/reducer, I found out that ChainMapper, ChainReducer are written for the "old" API (classes in package org.apache.hadoop.mapred). What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also searching for the same. I did get the answer and even though its late I thought sharing this may help someone.

From Hadoop 2.0 onwards you can find ChainMapper and ChainReducer in the package **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain**

ChainMapper usage pattern:

```
...
Job job = new Job(conf, "MyJob");

Configuration map1Conf = new Configuration(false); 
... ChainMapper.addMapper(job, AMap.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, true, map1Conf);

Configuration map2Conf = new Configuration(false); 
... ChainMapper.addMapper(job, BMap.class, Text.class, Text.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, false, map2Conf);

Configuration map3Conf = new Configuration(false); 
... ChainReducer.setReducer(job, CReducer.class, Text.class, Text.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, false, map3Conf);
...

job.waitForComplettion(true);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/03/29/how-to-chain-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop.aspx). This shows how to make use of two JobConf to enable Chaining of Map Reduce Jobs instead of using ChainMapper/ChainReducer.

Comment: but addDependingJob just ensures that one is executed after another while ChainReducer is used to pass one's output directly to another's input so that disk usage is reduced.