# How to make chain Mapper in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop.

I want to achieve the chain like `Mapper->Reducer->Mapper`.I have found that `old api` could do it.But I have used `new api` to achieve my MapReduce. In `new api`, it has been changed to `ChainMapper` and `ChainReducer`.I have searched its doc, but the example can not give a way.Some solution in stackover flow like this:

[how-to-chain-mapper-reducer-in-hadoop-1-0-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499107/how-to-chain-mapper-reducer-in-hadoop-1-0-4)

It gives a way to achieve `Mapper->Mapper->Reducer`.It's not what I want.

The hadoop which I used is `2.5.2`.

How do I to achieve it using `new api`?

Thanks!

Comment: try this https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html

Comment: @urug the example has used `old api`.